# PHP Find Function start and end

Tags: php, function

is there a way in which to find the start and end of a function?

basically i am wanting to write a piece of code that can look at a function and add code to the start or end of said function.

i thought this might be possible with str_replace/preg_replace for that start of the function but not too sure on how you can do it for the end of the function as there can be many } in a function and your not always guaranteed to get the right one.

is there any code snippet that produces the same functionality as say the bracket highlight in Notepad++?

FYI im using PHP 5 is that helps

Cheers

UPDATE

Sorry i didnt make this clear earlier - i need to do this in PHP as i want to write a class that can add code to functions at certain points.

Comment: If your code is properly indented you can just look for `function ...` and `}` at some indentation level.

Comment: Have a look at the tokenizer.

Comment: thanks @kingCrunch looks like that might do the trick - will leave this open incase a better response comes along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would to give the credit for this answer to @KingCrunch tokenizer, although hard to get your head round does indeed do the job :)